# Floating image to the right

Tags: html, image, css-float

I would like to float the image in div#rakshak to the right of div#MainMenu. How can I fix the css in the site below

[site removed]

Comment: Change float to left on #MainMenu.  You may have to play around a bit, but you should get the idea.

Comment: @apurv Just in case you didn't notice.. The ink pot is getting cut by header and footer when you scroll up and down.

Comment: Thanks @Playmaker. I am aware of that and tried fixing it by using z-index. However, that didn't fix the issue

Comment: You can't ask our users to visit your website and debug it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the floats of both the main menu div and rakshak div set to right.

I suggest you either change the menu to float left, which will fix the issue, else you change the order of the divs

**option 1**

```
#MainMenu {
float: left;
clear: right;
margin-right: -8px;
margin-top: 42px;
}
```

**Option 2**

```
<div id="MainHeader" class="pageWrapper clearfix">
                <h1 id="Logo"><a href="http://www.gauravgatha.org">    <img src="http://www.gauravgatha.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/logo.png" alt="Gaurav Gatha" width="140" height="40"></a></h1>
<div id="rakshak" style="clear: right;float:right; margin-top:35px;">
                        <a href="http://www.rakshakfoundation.org"><img src="http://www.gauravgatha.org/wp-content/themes/parallelus-salutation/assets/images/rakshak.png"></a>
                    </div>


                <div id="MainMenu">
                    <div class="inner-1">
                        <div class="inner-2">
                            <nav>

                                <div id="MM" class="slideMenu">
                                    <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-3552" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-3552"><a href="http://www.gauravgatha.org">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-3554" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-3554" style="z-index: 300; "><a href="#" class="hasSubMenu">Contest<span class="subDown"></span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu" style="top: 31px; display: none; visibility: visible; ">
    <li id="menu-item-3553" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3553"><a href="http://www.gauravgatha.org/contest/rules/">Rules and Regulations</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-3555" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3555"><a href="http://www.gauravgatha.org/contest/judging-criteria/">Judging Criteria</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-3556" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3556"><a href="http://www.gauravgatha.org/contest/the-jury/">The Jury</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-3557" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3557"><a href="http://www.gauravgatha.org/contest/rules/">Rules and Regulations</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-3558" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3558"><a href="http://www.gauravgatha.org/contest/important-dates/">Important Dates</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-3559" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-3559"><a href="#">Participate</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-3560" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3560"><a href="http://www.gauravgatha.org/faqs/">FAQs</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-3561" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3561"><a href="http://www.gauravgatha.org/contact/">Contact Us</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-3563" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-3563"><a href="http://www.rakshakfoundation.org/poem/" onclick="javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','outbound-menu','http://www.rakshakfoundation.org']);">Last Year Entries</a></li>
</ul>                                           <div style="clear:left"></div>
                                </div>

                            </nav>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>



            </div>
```

You will need to change style of main menu:

```
#MainMenu {
float: right;
margin-right: 20px;
margin-top: 42px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I used the option 2 :)

Answer (score 2):

Substitute their places in html (div#rakshak should be above div#MainMenu in html), remove clear:right from div#MainMenu and if you want increase its margin-right above 0 (my suggestion is 10px).

Answer (score 0):

change the position of rakshak and mainmenu or float left the main menu